# Wordpress database accidentally changed URL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have accidently changed my wordpress URL and Site URL in my wordpress admin. Now I cannot access my backend of the site, its throwing a 404 error.

How do I get back into the backend and edit the links I changed?

Thank you!!
Scott

Comment: Do you have FTP access to the web server?

Comment: Yes I do, I have entire access

Comment: If your hosting provider has a control panel see if phpMyAdmin or some other database tool is available.

Comment: Hi Dave yes I have this, not too sure where to look in phpMyAdmin

Comment: it that the situation you are in? https://www.e-systems.tech/blog/-/blogs/wordpress-changing-the-site-s-domain

Comment: Very strange update. Can access everything in the backend if I know the link. however if I just write '/wp-admin' after the domain they it comes up page not found. As this still goes to the old link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go in phphmyadmin and then open `wp_options` and find `siteurl`, `home` change with correct url. It will work.

Comment: Thanks changed this but still saying page not found. I dont understand!

Comment: Very strange update. Can access everything in the backend if I know the link. however if I just write '/wp-admin' after the domain they it comes up page not found. As this still goes to the old link.

Comment: Then find out in the url in phpmyadmin may be in some plugin may create the issue. You just find and replace the url it will work.